# Template do C#(SPA) não roda

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application

Fui fazer um teste com o Single Page Application, usando o template do visual studio. Bem, criei o projeto e não fiz nada, nada mesmo, apenas criei o projeto e rodei e ao rodar me deu esse erro:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ValdiateAntiForgeryToken'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   Teste_SPA   C:\Projetos\Teste_SPA\Teste_SPA \Controllers\ManageController.cs    200 Active

A questão é que o namespace: `System.Web.Mvc` já está no projeto. Se é referência, qual eu adiciono?

Comment: Acredito que seja um erro no template do projeto, pois `ValdiateAntiForgeryToken` não existe - parece ser um erro de digitação sobre `ValidateAntiForgeryToken`.

Comment: @Renan, eu não digitei nada. Apenas construir o projeto e fui rodar para ver a cara dele, apenas isso. Não foi digitado nada. O Atributo já estava lá.

Comment: Por isso que eu digo que o erro é do template. Parece um erro de digitação do autor do template, não seu. Quando você cria um projeto pelo Visual Studio, você utiliza um template (nesse caso, SPA), que tem um autor responsável. Isso pega mal pra Microsoft, que disponibiliza o template. Acredito que corrigir o erro é um primeiro passo para a aplicação rodar.

Comment: @Renan Bem provável que este template não seja da Microsoft. Pra todo efeito, o Renan está certo, é um erro de digitação de quem fez o template, ou a mensagem de erro na pergunta não está exatamente igual a que é mostrada pra você.

Comment: @Renan, obrigado. Agora entendi o que você quis dizer com erro de digitação. Resolvi. Muito obrigado pela ajuda e não resolução. Precisamos disso, que nos mostre o caminho apenas e não fazer por nós. Valeu. Posta como resposta que marco a resposta.

Comment: @Renan, só uma pergunta. Quando starto o projeto, a página que vem é a de Login e não a Index ou Home e não consigo alterar isso.

Comment: @pnet talvez o projeto tenha especificado por padrão alguma forma de autenticação - e como o usuário nunca autenticou, é direcionado a essa página. Acho que vale a pena abrir uma pergunta só pra isso, e também verificar o web.config pra ver se há algo sobre a forma de autenticação exigida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente isso é um erro de digitação - mas não seu!

A expressão `ValdiateAntiForgeryToken` presente na mensagem de erro parece muito com o método `ValidateAntiForgeryToken`, que deveria ser o correto.

Você cria aplicações e soluções no Visual Studio a partir de um template, que é a definição básica de um projeto vazio. O Visual Studio disponibiliza vários templates, nem todos da Microsoft, para você criar uma aplicação "do zero". O que parece que ocorreu aqui é que o autor do template que você utiliza cometeu um erro de digitação, então isso afetará todos os desenvolvedores que utilizarem o mesmo template.

Acredito que corrigir o erro do autor do template é o primeiro passo para conseguir fazer sua aplicação funcionar - mas dado um erro tão básico em um template disponibilizado para o VS, eu ficaria preocupado com outros erros que o template pode ter.

Em tempo: meu grau de confiança para com a corretude dos templates oficiais da Microsoft é bastante alto. Se tivesse que apostar, eu diria que esse veio da galeria do Visual Studio.